# Contour inegration involving a confluent hypergeometric function with a pole at zero

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, hypergeometric-function

I have the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 t^{-5/4} {_1}F_1(-1/4;1/2;t) dt
\end{equation}

I know that it only has a pole at zero since the confluent hypergeometric function is analytic in the entire complex plane but I dont know what contour to use.

Answer (score 0):

This integration does not have [a convergent result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5B%20t%5E(-5%2F4)*1F1%5B-1%2F4,1%2F2,t%5D,%7Bt,0,1%7D%5D).

$$
\int t^{-5/4} {_1}F_1(-1/4;1/2;t) dt
= \int t^{-5/4} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-\frac{1}{4})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_k} \frac{t^k}{\Gamma(k+1)} dt \\=\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-\frac{1}{4})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_k} \frac{\int t^{k-\frac{5}{4}}dt}{\Gamma(k+1)} =\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-\frac{1}{4})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_k (k-\frac{1}{4})}  \frac{t^{k-\frac{1}{4}}}{\Gamma(k+1)} $$

Since $k-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}+k-1 = \frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{4})(\frac{3}{4})_k}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})(-\frac{1}{4})_k}$

$$=\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-\frac{1}{4})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_k}\frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{4})(\frac{3}{4})_k}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})(-\frac{1}{4})_k}  \frac{t^{k-\frac{1}{4}}}{\Gamma(k+1)} =\frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4}) \sqrt[4]{t}} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-\frac{1}{4})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_k}\frac{(\frac{3}{4})_k}{(-\frac{1}{4})_k}  \frac{t^{k-\frac{1}{4}}}{\Gamma(k+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4}) \sqrt[4]{t}}  {_2}F_2(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};t)$$

When $t \to 1$, $\frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4}) \sqrt[4]{1}}  {_2}F_2(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};1) \approx -4.75045$ by [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B-1%2F4%5D%2F(Gamma%5B3%2F4%5D)HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B-1%2F4,%20-1%2F4%7D,%20%7B1%2F2,%203%2F4%7D,%201%5D).

When $t = 0$, ${_2}F_2(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};0)= 1$ and $\frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})} =-4$. But on the denominator, the $\sqrt[4]{t} =0 $. So it becomes $\frac{-1}{0}$ form, which means the lower limit of integration doesnot exists.

So $\int_0^1 t^{-5/4} {_1}F_1(-1/4;1/2;t) dt$ does not converge.